# How to add epics asynchronously?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-observable, rxjs6

I am able to add asynchronous reducer, but unable to add asynchronous epics

Following this link [Adding New Epics Asynchronously](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/recipes/AddingNewEpicsAsynchronously.html), I tried using `epic$.next()` but was unable to add new epic.

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore, compose } from 'redux';
import { createEpicMiddleware, combineEpics } from 'redux-observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import createReducer from '../reducers';
import mainEpic from '../config/epics';
```

Middleware configuration is given below:

```
const epicMiddleware = createEpicMiddleware();

const epic$ = new BehaviorSubject(mainEpic);
const rootEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  epic$.pipe(mergeMap(epic => epic(action$, state$)));
```

Store Enhancers for redux dev tools

```
const composeEnhancers =
  // compose;
  process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' &&
  window.navigator.platform !== 'iPad' &&
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
    ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
    : compose;
```

This is the instantiation of store

```
export default () => {
  const store = createStore(
    createReducer(),
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(epicMiddleware))
  );

  epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic);

  // Extra functionality to the store
  store.asyncReducers = {};
```

Here, I call injectRepics (Repics for reducer and epics) with parameters `key`, `reducer`, `newEpic` when new component is bound asynchronously

```
  store.injectRepics = (key, reducer, newEpic) => {
    if (!store.getState()[key]) {

      // here I get newEpic
      console.log(newEpic);

      // new reducer is added to asyncreducer object
      store.asyncReducers[key] = reducer;
      // new reducer is created and replaced
      store.replaceReducer(createReducer(store.asyncReducers));

      // -------------------------------------
            But, I'm unable to replace epic
      // -------------------------------------
      newEpic && epic$.next(newEpic);

      // epicMiddleware.run(rootEpic);
      // newEpic && addNewEpic(newEpic);
    }
  };

  return store;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a simple mistake.

I forgot to add combineEpics in new epic.

So, the code becomes `newEpic && epic$.next(combineEpics(...newEpic))`